# Find strong name signature without calling LoadAssembly

Tags: c#

When reading a Windows PE file directly, I can't seem to find the strong name of a delay signed assembly.  I can get to the CLR Header and read all the CLR header entries including the flags and the StrongNameSignature field.  Unfortunately in a delay signed assembly the StrongNameSignature is zeroed out.  Is the information in the MetaData directory specified within the CLR header?  If so does anyone have an example of how to read this table?

I am not interested in calling ILDASM or loading the assembly.

Comment: Why do you not want to call ILDASM or load the assembly?  This information may help us form a better answer.

Comment: I have a small stand alone utility that displays the CLR flags and some additional data for all assemblies in a folder.  It would be nice to throw the strong name in the output, but not if it requires launching a new process or loading an assembly for reflection only in a new app domain and dealing with any potential 32/64 bit issues.

Comment: I added the link I mentioned in my answer. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an Assembly is delay signed, as you have found, the signature is not written to the assembly since it is not yet signed.

You can get the public key which is in the Assembly Manifest, and the public key token is the first 8 bytes of the SHA1 hash of the public key (IIRC).

So If you do not want to load the assembly you will need to locate the Manifest and parse the data.

I did a quick 'bing' and found the following 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/asmex.aspx

it might help as a starting point with the details of parsing the manifest, but I confess I did not look deeply into it.

Comment: OK, but the 'Assembly Manifest' is located within the MetaData directory.  I can't seem to find any details regarding the format of the MetaData tables or any examples of how to read it. 

You mentioned a link?

Comment: :) thats what you get when your are answering a question and the wife is dragging you out the door... Sorry about that.

Comment: Asmex was exactly what I needed to get moving in the right direction.  I could not find details of the MetaData tables documented anywhere else.  Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to reflect upon the assembly without loading it.

The easiest way to get a copy of Mono.Cecil is to install MonoDevelop and dive into the install directory.

Building it yourself is not always the simplest thing.

Also - Mono.Cecil is a standalone assembly, IIRC, and does not depend on Mono.